# Writing a debugger for php

Tags: php, .net, debugging

I am quite dissapointed of the debuggers and servers that are available on the market for php.

I am planning to make my own mini-web server for php with a debugger.

I want to do this in .NET.

A very basic IDE might also be required (I guess a notedpad with some color coding).

I don't think the server will be a problem, since all i need to do is interop with the php executable and return output.

However the debugging part seems quite a daunting task. I have never written a debugger before, so I would like to get some guidelines on how to design a debugger for php and where to start.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't know where to start, what makes you think that you can do better than people who do?

Comment: Have you not used the php debug tools in Eclipse?

Comment: wowser, a pretty big/deep question

Comment: You're not satisfied with [dbg](http://www.php-debugger.com/dbg/)?

Comment: I want something that works out of the box. I don't want to configure debuggers and servers and all that. I want a solution that once you click on debug you start debug - no config, no hassles. Thats what i am aiming for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write the debugger. You can use the xdebug extension and the http://www.xdebug.org/docs-dbgp.php DBGp protocol. It's easy to interface with that, but you are completely free in designing a frontend upon it. (There is even one in Python http://code.google.com/p/pdbg/, which might by utilizable with IronPython?)

It's not very encompassing with features, but you can easily execute in-PHP callbacks to retrieve additional debugging information.